# Unable to run ArcPy in VS Code?

Tags: arcpy, ide, visual-studio-code

I am having some trouble running arcpy in VS Code. When I run my simple test scrtipt:

```
import arcpy

in_shp = r'S:\CVT\ChesterfieldTwp\Data\GIS\Layers\Utilities\SanitarySewer.shp'

for field in arcpy.ListFields(in_shp):
    print(field.name)
```

VS Code throws an error:

```
Exception has occurred: GeneratorExit
File "C:\Users\adoezema\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 44, in <genexpr>
  if not any(e in sys.version for e in ("Continuum", "conda-forge", "Anaconda")):
File "C:\Users\adoezema\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
  if not any(e in sys.version for e in ("Continuum", "conda-forge", "Anaconda")):
File "C:\Users\adoezema\OneDrive - OHM Advisors\ArcTools, Models, and Scripts\Lynda Courses\Scratch.py", line 1, in <module>
import arcpy
 File "C:\Users\adoezema\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\adoezema\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "C:\Users\adoezema\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

[image]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you please confirm that you can run that code in the ArcGIS Python terminal? Also, are you able to `import arcpy` in your above IDE?

Comment: I can run the above code in ArcPro, ArcMap, and PyCharm.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/56082919/820534

Answer (score 1):

Completely uninstalled and reinstalled vs code. This seemed to fix the issue.